# Getting wet when thinking of a man

Tags: halal-haram, salat, women

Hello everybody I am a muslim women. I have been talking with someone, a man. He was hitting on me but I told him I can't date if I have no intention marrying him. Now the problem is when I recall our conversations I get wet. There were times were it was him saying explicit sexual questions (are you a virgin, i want to kiss, I am in love with you such things) and other times we were talking in a platonic way. When I recall all of that (sexual or not) I get wet. And I was wet but I went on doing my ablution and pray. Did I do it right? Was I supposed to wash my private parts and change my clothes (because I was not wearing any panties) in the first place before doing my ablution and praying. Please help me. I have a voice in my head telling me that my prayers won't be accepted. And I can't stop rethinking about my conversations with that man which means getting all wet.  Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking about the conversations you had with the man, it is haram because he isn't your husband in islam. Thinking of him isn't doing you any good. In case you're in doubt just do the ghusl for your prayers to be accepted.